# replace operators with low level functions

Tags: python, scripting

While it is extremely easy to find operator calls (by inspecting the user interface and the info window), I have big difficulties to actually find the low level alternative functions which I can (or should) use in my scripts instead of the operators.

One recent example was:

- operator call: `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu()`
- RNA method call: `obj.keyframe_insert("location",frame=frame)`

Finding the operator was a matter of less than a minute. The low level function came to me as a comment about improving my code example.

So I wonder where I could find answers to questions of the type:

> "what function(s) can I use to replace this operator... ?"

For me the blender API is not helpful for answering this type of question and google only helped me in few cases.

Of course I could post a question here every time I want to know more about a specific operator. But maybe there is a better alternative (document, gotcha, tip, tutorial...) that I overlook?

Comment: Concerning the API ref: The API is "object orientated". So starting from the "object" to manipulate works usually ok. What could help is ignoring bpy.ops for the most part and starting from bpy.data and going down to bpy.types. Sometimes overlooked are the inherited member below on the page.

Comment: Did you read http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_api_reference.html ? Especially the section *Simple Data Access* is important, because it tells you about the **References** section on `bpy.types` pages. Note that `obj.keyframe_insert(...)` is **not** low level. Low level keyframe creation is shown here: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_quickstart.html#animation

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to create a collection of information resources:

**From API documents**

- Inspect the inherited Functions Section at the page bottom.

**From within the Python Console**

- Inspect bpy.data...
- Inspect bpy.types...

**List of useful reference documents**

- [Reference API Quickstart](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_quickstart.htm) (Blender 2.71 API)
- [Reference API usage](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_api_reference.html) (Blender 2.71 API)

Comment: Maybe it is useful to collect a list of useful information sources here ?